# What is the best way for sorting string according specific data

Tags: c++, sorting, containers

I get through tcp protocol 8 lines from different devices.

Example of the lines:
"12:10:00, gs, continue, break/n".

How can I enter both of the result (8 lines from each source) to a sort container (map or prioriy_queue? It should sort them according to the first data (time)?

Comment: i find the question a bit confusing , i think you should be more specific, but if you want to know, `std::map` has a special template type that can be specified in order to have a custom sorting algorithm. By default `std::map` uses `std::less` that calls `operator <` from `std::string`. Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Either by parsing it into an object whose `operator<` compares on the first field, or by providing a custom comparator which uses, eg. `std::strncmp` if you're storing C strings, or the appropriate `std::string::compare` overload if you're storing std::strings.

Comment: Use a std::set with a comparator. A compactor can be alamda or functor that will split the string and compare the first date(time).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>


class TimeComparator
{
public:
    inline static unsigned long int converToSecond(std::string time)
    {
            std::string delemeter = ":";
            std::vector<std::string> dataVec;
            size_t pos = 0;
            while((pos = time.find(delemeter)) != std::string::npos)
            {
                    dataVec.push_back(time.substr(0, pos));
                    time.erase(0, pos + delemeter.length());
            }
            int hour = atoi(dataVec[0].c_str());
            int min = atoi(dataVec[1].c_str());
            unsigned long int seconds = hour*60*60 + min*60;
            return seconds;
    }
    inline static bool compareTimeInHHMMFormat(std::string lhsTime, std::string rhsTime)
    {
            unsigned long int lhsSec = converToSecond(lhsTime);
            unsigned long int rhsSec = converToSecond(rhsTime);
            if(lhsSec <= rhsSec)
                    return true;
            else
                    return false;
    }
};


class Comparator
{
public:
    bool operator() (const std::string lhs, const std::string rhs) const
    {

            std::vector<std::string> vec;
            std::vector<std::string> timeVec;
            vec.push_back(lhs);
            vec.push_back(rhs);
            auto it = vec.begin();
            for(it; it != vec.end(); it++)
            {
                    std::istringstream ss(*it);
                    std::string token;
                    std::getline(ss, token, ',');
                    timeVec.push_back(token);
            }
            return TimeComparator::compareTimeInHHMMFormat(timeVec[0], timeVec[1]);
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::string input1 = "12:10:00, gs, continue, break/n";
    std::string input2 = "10:10:00, gs, continue, break/n";
    std::set<std::string, Comparator> timeSet;
    timeSet.insert(input1);
    timeSet.insert(input2);
    std::copy(timeSet.begin(),timeSet.end(),       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

Output:
techie@gateway2:myExperiments$ ./a.out
10:10:00, gs, continue, break/n
12:10:00, gs, continue, break/n
```

Comment: Why not to use a container which already sorts? like prioriy_queue?

Comment: I want to enter  all of the 8 ines together to the queue.

Comment: @sarar Set also stores the data in sorted order. Since the sorting required here is particularly based on first sub string so we have to write your own custom comparator. Same with any container that stores content in sorted order. What do you mean by all lines together ? You just need to get the 8 lines and split into 8 strings and then insert into the container. In this way each line will be stored in sorted order.

Comment: The problem is that no two elements in the container can have equivalent key in set container (I might have strings with the same time).

Comment: @sarar You can use multiset for this. In multiset you can store multiple keys with same name. Just return true for <= condition in the comparator function, thats it.